# How to find all available networking interfaces, having IP address assigned or not

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to get all networking interfaces available on linux. I am using ioctl API to get all the networking interfaces but it return me only the interfaces those have ip address allocated. It could be better illustrated by code:

```
struct ifconf            ifc;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFCONF, & ifc);
```

As ioctl to get no of networking interfaces can only work with AF_INET style I have to used it but because of this it return me only the networking interfaces those have assigned with IP. But if there are some network interfaces available those have not assigned any IP then these interfaces are not returned by ioctl. Is there any another way to get them?

Comment: You could try and parse `/proc/net/dev`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that was really helpful. From /proc/net/dev I can get the names of interfaces but from here I can not get MAC address and MTU ?

Comment: `/sys/class/net` is another place to dig in.

Comment: @SamiLaine that works I can find there all the information I need. Thank you so much :)

Comment: in case if I want to get it from ioctl command then is it possible?